# Damaged SD card (badly unmounted?) How to fix?

Tags: 12.04, filesystem, sd-card

First Off I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a laptop with a built in card reader.

I have a sandisk 8Gig micro sd card that came with my HTC Desire HD phone.

Unfortunately I had mounted it to a windows computer at work via a usb cable attached to the phone and didn't "safely remove hardware". This was not the first time I didn't "safely remove" it from windows and each time I accidentally did so, I had to restart my phone before the sd card was accessible again.

It must have worn out something though because now my phone won't recognize the card at all and when I put it into my laptop's card reader I get the following errors in /var/log/syslog

```
Apr  4 21:17:59 jesse-laptop kernel: [12665.532025] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
Apr  4 21:18:00 jesse-laptop kernel: [12667.192024] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
Apr  4 21:18:02 jesse-laptop kernel: [12668.860020] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
Apr  4 21:18:04 jesse-laptop kernel: [12670.532020] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
```

I have googled this message but can't find anywhere that explains what it means. All of the posts regarding similar errors that I found are about getting card readers to work, but my card reader works perfectly when I insert a different sd card.

```
Apr  4 21:26:35 jesse-laptop kernel: [13182.192121] mmc0: new SDHC card at address b368
Apr  4 21:26:35 jesse-laptop kernel: [13182.195849] mmcblk0: mmc0:b368       29.8 GiB 
Apr  4 21:26:35 jesse-laptop kernel: [13182.197931]  mmcblk0: p1
```

So I know the problem is with the damaged card not the reader.

The problem seems to be with initializing the card because it doesn't appear under /dev/ anywhere I can find. When I insert a working SD card it appears as /dev/mmcblk0 & the partition is /dev/mmcblk0p1.

Needless to say I can't format the card or run any recovery software until I can get it to appear as a device.

*Edit: - I have discovered by looking at my syslog [relevant parts available here](http://www.windwanderer.com/system/files/syslog_sd_card.) that when I first inserted my card the error was different to what it is now. I don't really understand any of these errors. I'm guessing the card was left in a state of anticipating a transfer (if that's possible) and it didn't receive it. Now it can't be initialized (whatever that actually means)*

Any help regarding what this error means and/or how to recover data from my sd card is very much appreciated. Most of my important data was backed up but there was one note taking application (on my phone) that wasn't and I'd like very much to retrieve that data.

*P.S. Both the working card and the damaged card are micro sd and I'm using a card adapter to insert them into my computer.*

*P.P.S. I've uploaded an annotated version of my /var/log/syslog with just the [relevant parts here](http://www.windwanderer.com/system/files/syslog_sd_card.) and also the [full syslog here](http://www.windwanderer.com/system/files/syslog_full.)*

Comment: I am not sure this belongs here?? But in windows you could try formatting the card, and using a software like "Recuva" to see if there is anything it is able to recover

Comment: I hope you have a backup? Try another card reader, and another card adapter. Can you format the card? Or is even that impossible? In my experience, formatting the card is the best way to fix problems with sdcards.

Comment: This Q/A site is about *Ubuntu Linux* not Windows. For Windows related problems ask on [su].

Comment: Please reopen this question. I'm asking here because _I only have Ubuntu_ I don't use any other OS and I need to understand what the error message that _ubuntu_ gives me means.

Comment: The Windoez computer that broke my card was one at work and I can't play around with that. Even if I could I wouldn't know where to start because I've only had Ubuntu PCs since 2006. :-D

Comment: No my card can't even be initialized. I've edited the question a bit to make that clear. I have one set of notes that were NOT backed up :-( **My current questions:** Any idea where a card appears in the filesystem BEFORE it's initialized? Do I need to somehow work with the card reader directly? What system is responsible for initializing cards and how do I interact with it?
-- I'll google all those tomorrow evening. I've run out of time for today. :-)

Comment: Voting to re-open.

Comment: My advice would be to try to find a friend with a Windows computer. Yes I understand that you work with linux since 2006 and don't have access to a windows pc, but I think that there are much better tools for this under windows, simply because many more people run into problems with sdcards under windows, not because of windows, but because there are many more windows users that use sdcards. I have a mac since 1999 and use ubuntu at work since four years, but still keep an old laptop with xp for problems like these.

Comment: Thanks I see your point. I did try it on a friends windows machine last night and it wasn't detected normally. However, I didn't install any special software either so that is still something I will need to try. I'm googling the questions above now and if I find answers for using windows I'll need to go to my parents place some time and try to use theirs. :-s

Comment: On windows/mac, this tool may help: https://www.sdcard.org/downloads/formatter_4/

Comment: First thing to do is trying to get the card to appear again. It may sound weird, but it happened to me many times to have problems to see a faulty drive under `/dev/` with Ubuntu and "recent" kernels, while other distros with kernel 2.6 where much more "nice" with the device. If you can, try to boot with [RIPLinux](http://www.tux.org/pub/people/kent-robotti/looplinux/rip/), which should be "old enough". Try also [SystemrescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage), better if a version from ~2012. If you manage to see the device, then I can suggest how to recover the data.

Answer (score 11):

It looks like the card has been damaged due to premature removal. The messages indicate either a controller failure in the card or bad blocks. The latter may be recoverable. Try this to recover:

- Insert card
- Unmount it with `umount /dev/mmc0` (or with whatever the drive is mounted as)
- `fsck -v /dev/mmc0`
- mount it

If this doesn't help, you have to reformat with `mkfs`.
If the card is still unusable, the controller has probably been damaged in hardware beyond recovery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but unfortunately I can't find the card under /dev/ at all. I've edited the question to reflect this. I've also noticed that initially the errors were different. See the _Edit:_ above :-)

Comment: @thecarpy you should post your own answer instead of editing this one.

Comment: @JessetheWindWanderer yes, Linux can be rather depressing like this. Trying to follow an answer is nigh on impossible with all the distributions (and even versions within the distribution) doing things differently.

Comment: in my case it was /dev/mmcblk0. MMC is SdCard. 
Also: My linux didn't auto-detect the filesystem.  When using mount or fsck, i used mount -t ntfs ...  @zx485

Answer (score -5):

Try using gparted to create a new partition table. Open gparted from the Dash or with `gksu gparted` in a terminal, then select your device, and go to Device -> New Partition Table.

Comment: This doesn't recover the data - a new partition table will screw up the data itself and prevent access - it's basically a sure-fire way to lose data.

Comment: Why would you partition the device? I don't think it would help